# Javascript: how to append sub-object into object?

Tags: javascript, object, append, subobject

I have tried several things, including using a constructor function, and the code below, none have worked. I thought this would be simple, how do I do this?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Creating a JavaScript Object.</p>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
var name ={ // subobject
    firstName : "John",
    lastName  : "Doe",
};
var person = {
name: {} // want to append here
};
person.name = name;
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =
person.name.firstName + " " + person.name.lastName;
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: works fine here http://jsfiddle.net/cwj89a0u/

Comment: What you've written should work. You can also do `var person = { name: name };`

Comment: Can you turn your question into an executable snippet that reproduces the problem?

Comment: @charlietfl Great, thanks. For some reason it didn't work in w3schools test box. I will use that site instead from now on.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the variable or the sub-object itself:

```
var person = {
    name: name
};
```

Or if you use the sub-object,

```
var person = { 
    name: { // subobject
        firstName : "John",
        lastName  : "Doe",
    }
};
```

Comment: there is no json in the question, json is a string data format